# Entity Framework Core и Lazy Load

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Осваиваю Entity Framework Core, возникло непонимание работы с Navigation Properties и в частности как должна работать Lazy load.

Модель `Competition` имеет связь многие к одну с моделями: `Player` (в каждом соревновании по два участника), `Arbitor`, `Tournament`.

```
public class Competition
{
    [Key]
    public int CompetitionID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Player1ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Player2ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ArbitorID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TournamentID { get; set; }
    public Result? MatchResult { get; set; }

    public virtual Player Player1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Player Player2 { get; set; } 
    public virtual Arbitor Arbitor { get; set; }
    public virtual Tournament Tournament { get; set; }
}

public class Player 
{
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Competition> Player1Competitions { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Competition> Player2Competitions { get; set;}
}

public class Arbitor
{
    [Key]
    public int ArbitorID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Seniority { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Competition> Competitions { get; set; }
}
```

Модель `Tournament` опущена за ненадобностью при рассмотрении проблемы.
Так как `Competition` имеет два FK `Player`, явно прописал связи:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Competition> ()
            .HasOne ( m => m.Player1 )
            .WithMany ( n => n.Player1Competitions )
            .HasForeignKey ( m => m.Player1ID );

        modelBuilder.Entity<Competition> ()
            .HasOne ( m => m.Player2 )
            .WithMany ( n => n.Player2Competitions )
            .HasForeignKey ( m => m.Player2ID );
}
```

Возникшие проблемы:

1. Насколько я понимаю, обозначая свойство как `virtual`, мы используем `Lazy load`. Но тогда почему, если мне нужно получить запись `Competition` (со всеми свойствами), я должен явно включать каждое свойство:

   ```
           var competition = await _context.Competitions
           .Include(c => c.Arbitor)
           .Include(c => c.Player1)
           .Include(c => c.Player2)
           .Include(c => c.Tournament)
           .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CompetitionID == id);
   ```

   Если не прописываю `Include`, то свойства остаются `null`. Но ведь они должны подгружаться самостоятельно при ленивой загрузке?

   2.Схожая ситуация с коллекцией объектов, тоже объявленной как `virtual`. Разве при ленивой загрузке коллекция не должна подгружаться без явного включения? Также насколько я понимаю, при ленивой загрузке вложенные свойства должны также подгружаться (так для каждого `Competition` должен подгрузиться необходимый `Arbitor`). Но явно включая коллекцию и проходя по объектам, вложенные свойства остаются равны `null`. Как в таком случае подгружать все вложенные свойства?

   ```
           var player = await _context.Players
           .Include ( s => s.Player1Competitions )
           .Include ( s => s.Player2Competitions )
           .SingleOrDefaultAsync ( m => m.PlayerID == id );
   ```

Comment: На сколько я знаю, core версия фреймворка не умеет в Lazy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[В EF сore фича lazy loading доступна с 2.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading)

Если очень хочется понять разницу между Eager - Lazy - Implicit, то делайте тренировочные проекты на EF 6.

PS Я лично вообще считаю, что Lazy loading нужно отключить и не включать. Причина проста: явное лучше неявного. Вы можете управлять тем, что подключать и когда подключать, а не тянуть кучу лишнего из базы.

Comment: Хорошо. Но как быть в моём случае, если нужно подгрузить свойство Player1 в Competitions (последний фрагмент кода в моём вопросе: в каждом элементе коллекции нужно подгрузить все свойства). Можете подсказать, пожалуйста.

Comment: @МаксимУстелемов [ThenInclude](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.3.php)? ([NB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45658411/5752652))