# Игнорируется связь One-to-Many в IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть следующий контекст БД:

```
public class AppIdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<UserAccount, UserRole, int>
{
    public AppIdentityContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<RefreshToken>()
            .HasKey(rt => rt.Refresh);

        builder.Entity<RefreshToken>()
            .HasOne(rt => rt.UserAccount)
            .WithMany(ua => ua.RefreshTokens)
            .HasForeignKey(rt => rt.UserId);
    }
}
```

Сами классы сущностей:

```
public class UserAccount : IdentityUser<int>
{
    // other properties

    public virtual ICollection<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
}

public class RefreshToken
{
    public string Refresh { get; set; }
    // other properties

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }
}
```

Далее я получаю `RefreshToken` в методе:

```
public async Task<RefreshToken> GetByRefreshAsync(string token)
{
    return await _context.RefreshTokens.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Refresh == token);
}

//...

var currentToken = await _tokenRep.GetByRefreshAsync(refreshToken);

if (currentToken.UserAccount == null)
{
    //...
}
//...
```

Так вот, похоже, что он игнорирует связь, установленную ранее в DbContext, потому что `UserAccount` всегда `null`.

Судя по логам, он не запрашивает `UserAccount` ни в момент получения `RefreshToken`, ни в момент обращения к полю `UserAccount`.

Если же явно запросить пользователя, то всё отрабатывает отлично.

```
var userAccount = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(currentToken.UserId.ToString());
if (userAccount == null)
{
    //...
}
//...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF до 2.1 не поддерживает ленивую загрузку, даже если у вас именно 2.1 её нужно отдельно включать.

Включив нужно проверить, что выполнены условия для ленивой загрузки (классы публичные, свойства виртуальные).

Ну и традиционно рекомендую не включать ленивую загрузку, указывать явно в каждом случае, что вам нужны за поля. Подгрузите их явно:

```
await _context.RefreshTokens.Include(x => x.UserAccount )
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Refresh == token);
```

См. также:

- [Entity Framework Core и Lazy Load](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/808754/213987)